# Scheduling a repetitive task in Android

Tags: android

In an Activity, I need to call a web service every 30 seconds or so, and use the data to update the UI.

How can I schedule a repetitive task?

Comment: I found this article to be helpful: http://cart.kolix.de/?p=1438

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is in a running activity, you could use [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)/[`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) and a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), or you could use [`postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) and an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 3):

You will want to create a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html) is a brief code example.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to acquire the `WakeLock` if you want this to be running after the screen is turned off (or more accurately, to prevent the CPU from shutting down). Use of `AlarmManager` is another alternative.