# Android regular task (cronjob equivalent)

Tags: java, android, timer, cron

The last time this question was asked (by a different user), the answer response was:

> If this is in a running activity, you could use Timer/TimerTask and a Handler, or you could use postDelayed() and an AsyncTask.

Here: [Android Repetitive Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517468/android-repetitive-task)

I am still learning how to program android. I have gone through the skills I do know including threads and had many issues with my code. Can anyone give an example of how to use: time/timertask and handler OR postDelayed() and AsyncTask.

Comment: The reference from google is actually quite good. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 23):

For Cron like tasks you have to use AlarmManager, this is a system service, for using it in your code you need to call:

```
AlarmManager myAlarmManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE).
```

Full docs about AlarmManager [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: How to set repeating for alarm manager IF i have a cron expression?!

Answer (score 5):

The most suitable approach is through services. I learned how to write services by looking at the source code for the stock Email app that is included with Android.

The general idea is that you override the [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) class, and set up [alarms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to activate your service. Unlike daemons and Windows services, Android services aren't always running - they start up (usually when activated by an alarm), perform work, then shut down. In some cases, you may need to acquire a [partial wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) to keep the service going until it completes the task - otherwise, Android may kill your service prematurely.

Comment: What do you do while the (Background) service is updating the DB and the user hits the app to open it?

Comment: Why would that make any difference? [SQLite is a transactional database](http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html) with full support of ACID

Comment: But what if the data displayed in your current view has gone stale, say a minute before the service starts to update the data?

Comment: You have two options - you can either periodically check for "fresher" data, or perform all your writes through a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). In which case, [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) will automatically update any lists that rely on such data, and you can use [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) to be notified of updates to other content.

Comment: Does using content provider score over using Write ahead logging?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to build a cronjob runner then what you want is a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html):

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service and it will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to another application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC). For example, a service might handle network transactions, play music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the background.

Comment: A service is not very much like a cronjob, see the answer below about AlarmManager.