# Android Java - How to make my program loop

Tags: java, android

How can I loop a program? Do I add code to OnActivity after existing code to make it restart to a certain place in the code?

I have an IF THEN statement, which at the end I want it to goto a portion of the code where it activates the TTS not from very begining where I have a button to start....

Thank you.
Flinx

Comment: What kind of program are you making? Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: You need to provide much, much more information. What exactly do you mean by "loop a program"?

Comment: Maybe you can post your source code so that we have something to work with.

Comment: You might check out this thread for scheduling regular tasks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266878/android-regular-task-cronjob-equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a part of the program to execute again, you can just use a `while` loop, or a `for` loop for a definite number of runs:

```
while(someFlag) {
  // run your program
}

// or
for(int i = 0; i < numRuns; i++) {
  // run your program
}
```

If you want the actual program to run multiple times, an [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) would probably work the best.

Comment: True. But this exists: http://www.imoseyon.com/2011/02/cron-on-android-is-awesome.html

Comment: [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) would be preferable to cron, but you're right.

Comment: @DavidCaunt thanks updated accordingly.