# Android app that can do sending data to data base using time interval

Tags: java, android, time, intervals

this time i really have no idea

I'm suppose to make a program that running on android device that can change data according to time using java
for example: If you in location A, than the app will send your location to the data base, and 1 minutes after, if you still on location A, the app will send to the data base your location, i mean coordinate

so the app suppose to sand any change in interval time of 1 minutes, anyone now how?
please help me

Comment: Too broad for a question. You should try to break the problem into smaller problems and try to figure out the parts.

Comment: ok, I'm sorry about my english
what I want to know is what is the function that make me can use the time interval to send data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android regular task (cronjob equivalent)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266878/android-regular-task-cronjob-equivalent)

Comment: Thx everyone
from the bottom of my heart, Thank you