# How to periodically call a Method in an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Im developing an Android app, and I need to periodically (a few times per second) execute some code from the UI thread, the Activity class. 
I have seen similar problems like here [Android repetitive task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517468/android-repetitive-task) but what I need is to set my Activity as a listener and somehow listen to a timer, so that every X milliseconds the activity executes a method.

Something like this:

```
class myActivity extends Activity{
    //things

    //This method must be called every X milliseconds
    private repetitive_method(){
      ....
    }

    //more things
 }
```

Is there some recomended way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is there:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: Link is dead. Here's the reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Note there is still a race condition where mActivity could become null between checking if it is null and calling `runOnUiThread()`.

```
class UpdaterThread extends Thread {
    /** Frequency / sleep duration in milliseconds */
    public static final int FREQUENCY = 250;        
    private volatile boolean mFinished;     
    private Activity mActivity;

    public UpdaterThread(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!mFinished) {
            try {
                if (mActivity != null) {
                    // Your method.
                    mActivity.runOnUiThread(repetitive_method());
                }
                Thread.sleep(FREQUENCY);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        }
    }

    public void quit() {
        mFinished = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would certainly work but the Timer and Handler classes provide interesting methods, notably to interact with UI threads and are therefore most common implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Timer myTimer;
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    myTimer= new Timer();
   //this will update every minute
    myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateMyTimerTask(), 0,
            60000);

}

public class UpdateMyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your method
         printAndroidLabel();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
     //stop timer
    myTimer.cancel();
}

public void printAndroidLabel(){
    System.out.println("Hi Android!");
}
```