# Not getting any response from Servlet Page

Tags: java, android, servlets

In Android I have written a program and making a request on a button click to Servlet Page and in response it will execute message written on that servlet page but when I am running my project its not doing anything on that button click.

Here is my code,

```
public static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/HttpGetServlet/HelloWorldServlet";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTxt);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view) 
{
    GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { URL });
}

private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
        String output = null;
        for (String url : urls) 
        {
            output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
        }
        return output;
    }

    private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) 
    {
        String output = null;
        try 
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return output;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String output) 
    {

        if(output==null)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        outputText.setText(output);
    }
}
```

If it can't find url then it should generate an Exception but i am catching exception then also nothing is happing.

Where i am wrong.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: did you getting Server Not Found Toast message?

Comment: @Hardik: No that is what i am saying that nothing is happening on button click :(

Comment: ok then from servlet you are returning a message right!?

Comment: yo just put this System.out.println("This is response "+output); and see is reponse is blank!!

Comment: @Hardik: Suppose I haven't create any servlet page then what it will do ?

Comment: then your response should be blank or null

Comment: @Hardik: Yeah when i am using debugger then the output value is `null`

Comment: ok then if you getting null why your toast message not appearing!!!

Comment: make sure it is null not in form of string "null"

Comment: @Hardik: yeah that is the problem its not displaying any Toast.

Comment: ok then your textview display any text?

Comment: @Hardik: At what line I supposed to check ? Actually I haven't done this type of servlet programming yet and try to doing it for the first time.

Comment: put this line on onPostExcecute method at first line System.out.println("This is response "+output); and see logcat

Comment: @Hardik: If the output value is `null` then how can TextView display any Text.. :/

Comment: @Hardik: OK Let me try

Comment: @Hardik: Yeah Now I have seen a Toast `Server Not Found` and a `This is response: null' on LogCat Screen but don't know why its not appearing before!

Comment: @Hardik: Can you please tell me how to make this request after every 2 minutes ?

Comment: put your toast message in all exceptions because in case of exceptions order matters if IO Exception occues it wont go in Exception block.

Comment: @pyus13: Can you please tell me how to make this request after every 2 minutes ? It will put this line in onCreate
`GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { URL });`
rather then putting it on `onClick` method. ?

Comment: @Android googling about timer android for repetitive task

Comment: @Android check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517468/android-repetitive-task

Answer (score 0):

```
       try 
            {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                System.out.println(output); // here you can check the value of the output String.
            }
```

If it has a value (it should) then  your problem is on your user interface.

Maybe you need to configure the way that your interface gets the response.